# Reciting Reverse Order Alphabet vs Reverse Order Counting

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, memory, cognitive-modeling

Observation A:
It's easy to recite the alphabet. It's hard to recite the alphabet backwards.

Observation B:
It's easy to recite the number 1 to 26. It's easy to recite the number 1 to 26 backwards.

How is the difference between A and B explained?

(I came across the first observation  in the book "How to Create a Mind" by Ray Kurzweil)

Comment: Maybe the reason is that we just "remember" the alphabet, wheras we know how to "generate" numbers, so we can easily generate the successor or previous of each number.

Comment: The sequences that are easy for you are easy because you've learned them already. Several points: A child who has just learned to count cannot count backwards because the child hasn't learned how yet. If you practice the alphabet backwards, you will learn it well. Unlike alphabets, number sequences can alternatively be learned by algorithm; so you can easily count down from 78,000 even if you've never done it before -- assuming you've learned the algorithm.

Comment: You tagged this with "cognitive-modelling". Do you want an example of how this could be implemented in a cognitive model?

Comment: @Seanny123 Yes, but only if it is a model that has explanotary power for human cognition.